# How to store the data and gives the audio and image using objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode8

I am developing an app for preschool learning app for kids.I used the code for learning  A-Z .

```
    alphabetsStoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a.png",@"b.png",@"c.png",@"d.png",@"e.png",@"f.png",@"g.png",@"h.png",@"i.png",@"j.png",@"k.png",@"l.png",@"m.png",@"n.png",@"o.png",@"p.png",@"q.png",@"r.png",@"s.png",@"t.png",@"u.png",@"v.png",@"w.png",@"x.png",@"y.png",@"z.png", nil];





    commonFunctionObject = [[SpeechCommonFunctions alloc]init];
    commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete = NO;
    counter = 0;
    isMicPresent = YES;
    _confirmationPopupView.hidden = true;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(repeatActionFire) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)repeatActionFire
{
    if(counter >= alphabetsStoreArray.count)
    {
        NSLog(@"finished");
        [_alphabetsShowImageView removeFromSuperview];
        [_speakerOrMicImageView removeFromSuperview];
        UIImageView *congratzView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        congratzView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"congratulation.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:congratzView];
         [self performSelector:@selector(navNew) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];           

    }
    else
    {
        [commonFunctionObject textToSpeechAction:alphabetsStoreArray :counter :_alphabetsShowImageView :_speakerOrMicImageView :isMicPresent];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(ActionToCkeckRecordCompletion) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

-(void)ActionToCkeckRecordCompletion
{
    if(commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete)
    {
        _confirmationPopupView.hidden = false;
    }
}
-(void)navNew

{
    v11=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"maincontroller"];
    [self presentViewController:v11 animated:NO completion:nil];

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (IBAction)playButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [commonFunctionObject recordPlayAction];
}

- (IBAction)nextButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    counter+=1;
    _confirmationPopupView.hidden = true;
    commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete = NO;
    if(commonFunctionObject.player.playing){[commonFunctionObject.player stop];}
    [self repeatActionFire];
}

- (IBAction)retryButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    _confirmationPopupView.hidden = true;
    commonFunctionObject.isRecordComplete = NO;
    if(commonFunctionObject.player.playing){[commonFunctionObject.player stop];}
    [self repeatActionFire];
}
```

This code is output as :A,B,C.....(AUDIO AND IMAGE ALSO DISPLAYED )

But,now

i need to store 3 images starting with A ex:apple,ant,airplane
and while button click i need as A for apple,A for Ant,A for Airplane(audio with image)
please rely if any ones knows.

Comment: You have to create an dictionary of array as like {"A":[apple, Ant, Airplane], "B":[....],...}. In this way you can perform search by key which is aplhabate & show appropriate outcome.

Comment: how to store ,can u  provide the code

Comment: depends on you. What you use to save & where too. I would prefer to go with core data. It will be faster & smarter than any other option.

Comment: can u give link to refer to do this in core data

Comment: I would suggest please go through the basics of coredata & coredata stack. WIll not take much time. Follow this link 1. https://www.raywenderlich.com/145809/getting-started-core-data-tutorial
2. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-core-data-stack--cms-20926